# Printing values one by one in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I use a servlet to get values from database and I want to print that in jsp. My problem is the values are printed like usera userb userc. I want the output to be like

```
usera 
userb
userc
```

Please help me to do this. Here is what i have tried

```
<%
String Users=request.getParameter("Users");
String User[]=Users.trim().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<User.length;i++){
    out.println(User[i]);
}
%>
```

Comment: I would recommend you using JSTL tags instead of JSP Scriptlets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are outputting html, you should add `<br />` after each user:

```
 out.println(User[i] + "<br />");
```

Note that it is not advisable to use java code in JSPs. Write your java code in a servlet, place the results as request attributes, and then forward to a JSP, where you can show the result using JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
String Users=request.getParameter("Users");
String User[]=Users.trim().split(" ");
for(int i=0;i<User.length;i++){
    out.println(User[i]+"<br/>");
}
%>
```

I would suggest you to go for JSTL

Here is how it should be :

Perform java code at servlet and forward request to a jsp file

Servlet :

```
String Users=request.getParameter("Users");
String User[]=Users.trim().split(" ");
request.setAttribute("name", User);
```

in that jsp file

```
<c:forEach var = "userName" items = "${name}">
<tr>
<font color="#000080"><td>${userName}</td></font>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

**See Also**

- [How to avoid java code in jsp files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [Servlet Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: I would **not** recommend using `<font>` tag. Rather use CSS for it.

Comment: whether the variable in request.setAttribute is User/Users?

Comment: @Sumithra I hope you have forwarded the request from servlet to jsp with same request response object. please check servlet info link for the same